# Plot that shows day of the week frequence in a df

Tags: python, plot, time-series

I got a web log showing the clicks and visitors, and can't plot frequence of days of the week from a dataframe in that format:

```
                      date
0      2017-06-03 00:07:04
1      2017-06-03 00:07:06
2      2017-06-03 00:07:07
3      2017-06-03 00:07:24
4      2017-06-03 00:07:38
```

I tried this:

```
Date_df = pd.DataFrame(dataset.date)

dates = pd.date_range('2017-06-01','2017-06-07', freq='D')
dates_count = Date_df.groupby(Date_df.date).count()['date']
dates_day_count = pd.DataFrame(dates_count)
dates_day_count = dates_day_count.rename(columns={"date":"Counts"})
dates_day_count.index.rename('date', inplace = True)
dates_day_count.tail()
```

But shows "`KeyError: 'date'`"

I wanna know the part of the day the site is most busy too (the hour of the day with most frequent), anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think need [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with [`dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html) or [`dt.hour`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.hour.html):

```
print (Date_df)
                 date
0 2017-06-03 00:07:04
1 2017-06-03 00:07:06
2 2017-06-04 00:07:07
3 2017-06-04 00:07:24
4 2017-06-04 00:07:38

dates_day_count = Date_df['date'].dt.date.value_counts().reset_index()
dates_day_count.columns = ['date','counts']
print (dates_day_count)
         date  counts
0  2017-06-04       3
1  2017-06-03       2
```

If want plot `date`s is possible use:

```
dates_day_count = Date_df['date'].dt.date.value_counts()
dates_day_count.plot.bar()
```

And for `hours`:

```
dates_day_count = Date_df['date'].dt.hour.value_counts()
dates_day_count.plot.bar()
```

Also if need some combinations e.g. dates with hours use [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) with http://strftime.org/:

```
dates_day_count = Date_df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H').value_counts()
```

Comment: how can I change that colors? haha it's very colorful every bar lmao